# Android database: how to update one column to be another column value?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Android database: how to update one column to be another column value?
For example,

```
Item
------------------------------------
id, name, suggestedPrice,  salesPrice
```

Update salesPrice to be suggestedPrice for all rows, SQL:

```
update Item set salesPrice=suggestedPrice
```

In android:

```
void execSQL(sql, bindingArg)
```

The android docs says: Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. The issue is that execSql(..) does not return the number of affected rows. Any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android docs are wrong. In theory, you are supposed to use the [update() function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])), but then you cannot use an SQL expression to compute the new value.

Just call `execSQL()`. To get the number of affected rows, call [changes()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) afterwards:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE ...", ...);
long rows = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, "SELECT changes()", null);
```

Comment: the execSQL() should return updated row count as JDBC. Thanks.

Comment: another update function is needed to support expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a long winded relatively generic solution.

Basically it uses the `SQLiteDatabase` `update` method obtaining the value from the respective row to be updated.

It's been made safe as such i.e the SQL `update Item set salesPrice=suggestedPrice` would update all rows.

It will only update one row according to the id column.

```
public long testUpdate(SQLiteDatabase db, 
                       String table, 
                       String getcolumn, 
                       String setcolumn, 
                       String idcolumn, 
                       Long id) {
    long rv = -1;
    boolean getcolumn_exists = false;
    boolean setcolumn_exists = false;
    boolean idcolumn_exists = false;
    boolean update_value_obtained = false;
    String updatevalue="";
    Cursor chk1 = db.query(table,
            null,null,null,null,null,null,
            "1"
    );
    for (String col: chk1.getColumnNames()) {
        if (col.equals(getcolumn)) {
            getcolumn_exists = true;
        }
        if (col.equals(setcolumn)) {
            setcolumn_exists = true;
        }
        if (col.equals(idcolumn)) {
            idcolumn_exists = true;
        }
    }
    chk1.close();
    if (!getcolumn_exists || !setcolumn_exists || !idcolumn_exists) {
        Log.d("TESTUPDATE","Missing Column(s) - Update not Attempted." +
                " :Column " + getcolumn + " exists=" + String.valueOf(getcolumn_exists) +
                " :Column " + setcolumn + " exists=" + String.valueOf(setcolumn_exists) +
                " :Column " + idcolumn + " exists=" + String.valueOf(idcolumn_exists)
        );
        return rv;
    }

    Cursor chk2 = db.query(
            table,
            new String[]{getcolumn},
            idcolumn + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null,null,null
    );
    if (chk2.moveToFirst()) {
        updatevalue =  chk2.getString(chk2.getColumnIndex(getcolumn));
        update_value_obtained = true;
    }
    chk2.close();
    if (!update_value_obtained) {
        Log.d("TESTUPDATE","Value not obtained - Update not Attempted. " +
                "Probably because ID " + String.valueOf(id) + " is not an existing column.");
        return rv;
    }
    Log.d("TESTUPDATE", "Attempting Update of " + setcolumn + " with value=" + updatevalue);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(setcolumn,updatevalue);
    rv =  db.update(table,cv,idcolumn + "=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    Log.d("TESTUPDATE", "Updated " + String.valueOf(rv) + " rows.");
    return rv;
}
```

The method requires 6 parameters :-

- 1) The SQLiteDatabase.
- 2) The name of the Table the update will be applied to.
- 3) The name of the column in the table from which the data to perform the update is to be obtanied from.
- 4) The name of the column that will be updated.
- 5) The name of the column that contains the ID (Note as it is **rowid**, ***rowid*** or **oid** will not work).
- 6) The ID of the row as a long.
- Note columns prefixed with the table name and the full stop separator, i.e. table.column, will also not work.

Relatively extensive checking is undertaken :-

- All three columns are checked to see if they exist (cursor with all columns is extracted for 1 row max).
- The existence of the row to be updated is checked as part of obtaining the value.
- Explanatory messages will be logged.

#### Example Use 1 (completes OK) :-

```
    dbhlpr.testUpdate(
            dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),   //SQLiteDatabase
            Datasource.TASKS_TABLE,         // TABLE
            Datasource.TASKS_EXPIRATION_COL,// COLUMN to get data from
            Datasource.TASKS_NAME_COL,      // Column to update
            Datasource.TASKS_ID_COL,        // ID Column
            10L                         // The ID to identify the row
    );
```

Result in Log :-

```
01-11 04:28:35.366 1897-1897/? D/TESTUPDATE: Attempting Update of _name with value=31/12/2018
01-11 04:28:35.370 1897-1897/? D/TESTUPDATE: Updated 1 rows.
```

#### Example Use 2 (Non-Existing columns - no update performed) :-

```
    dbhlpr.testUpdate(
            dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),   //SQLiteDatabase
            Datasource.TASKS_TABLE,         // TABLE
            "NOTACOLUMN",// COLUMN to get data from
            "ANOTHENOTACOLUMN",      // Column to update
            "YETANOTHERNOTACOLUMN",        // ID Column
            10L                         // The ID to identify the row
    );
```

Result in Log :-

```
01-11 04:35:03.261 1967-1967/mjt.adapters D/TESTUPDATE: Missing Column(s) - Update not Attempted. :Column NOTACOLUMN exists=false :Column ANOTHENOTACOLUMN exists=false :Column YETANOTHERNOTACOLUMN exists=false
```

#### Example Use 3 - Invalid (non-existent) ID :-

```
    dbhlpr.testUpdate(
            dbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),   //SQLiteDatabase
            Datasource.TASKS_TABLE,         // TABLE
            Datasource.TASKS_EXPIRATION_COL,// COLUMN to get data from
            Datasource.TASKS_NAME_COL,      // Column to update
            Datasource.TASKS_ID_COL,        // ID Column
            1123456789L                         // The ID to identify the row
    );
```

Result in the log :-

```
01-11 04:39:08.086 2030-2030/mjt.adapters D/TESTUPDATE: Value not obtained - Update not Attempted. Probably because ID 1123456789 is not an existing column.
```

Comment: Well elaborate.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya what do you believe needs elaborating?

Comment: Nope. Its fine.

Comment: update one row at a time? Too expensive for tables with thousand of rows. Thanks.